# Does Hazelcast has some similar functionality like PDX serialisation for queries?

Tags: hazelcast

I have some projects that I used Hazelcast but lately I was watching a presentation about Geode and they told something about PDX serialisation for queries....

They told, let's say I have a big object, with 50 fields and my queries will only base 2 fields, they told with PDX serialisation they could only deserialise these 2 fields and execute the query.....

Do we have something similar for Hazelcast?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, see [Portable](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.12/manual/html-single/index.html#implementing-portable-serialization) as a serialization type.

Comment: Also, if you're on 3.12, you have [JSON](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.12/manual/html-single/index.html#querying-json-strings) which works the same.